# To avoid repeating numbers in arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, repeat

My code is below. This is c++ code. 
This code makes common division in two number. 
For example if input is 18,24, output is 2,2,2,3,3. 
But I want to only 2 and 3 in output. 
I can't fix it. How can I fix this? Thanks for helping...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Ratio {
    public:
        Ratio(int numerator, int denumerator) {
            num=numerator;
            den=denumerator;
        }

        void commondivisor() {
            int arr[20];
            int arr2[20];
            int c=0;
            int c2=0;
            for (int q = 2; num != 1; q ++)
            {
                if (num % q == 0)
                {
                    num /= q;
                    arr[c]=q;
                    q --;
                   c++;   
                }
            }
            cout << endl;

            for (int w = 2; den != 1; w ++)
            {
                if (den % w == 0)
                {
                    den /= w;
                    arr2[c2]=w;
                    w --;
                    c2++;  
                }
            }

            for (int i=0; i<c; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<c2; j++) {
                    if (arr[i]==arr2[j])
                        cout<<arr2[j];
                }
            }
        }


    private:
        int num;
        int den;
};

int main() {

     int a;
     int b;
     cin >> a;
     cin >> b;
     Ratio nesne(a,b);
     nesne.commondivisor();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to find it before insertion ? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm for finding factors doesn't really work? For instance, for the numbers 18 and 24, it should be {1,2,3,6,9,18} and {1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24}, respectively - including 1 and the number itself. You get {2,3,3} and {2,2,2,3}, respectively.

```
std::vector<int> factors(int num) {
     std::vector<int> fac_vec;
     for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
         if (num % i == 0)
             fac_vec.push_back(i);
     return fac_vec;
 }
```

This works, thought it's by no means efficient. To find the common elements, you can iterate with a nested loop. Again, not very efficient, specially since the vectors/arrays are sorted. See example below.

```
std::vector<int> find_common(std::vector<int>& l, std::vector<int>& r) {
    std::vector< int > common_vec;
    for (auto il : l)
         for (auto ir : r)
             if (il == ir)
                 common_vec.push_back(ir);
    return common_vec;
 }
```